# Cannot change version for online Composer Playground

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am going through the instructions for creating a multi-org setup for hyperledger fabric, instructions are here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.

There is one step (Step 11) where you have to generate a business network archive (bna file). So the instructions tell you to create one from the [online Composer playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/), simply by changing the version number from the editor.

The problem is, it won't allow me to change the version number and deploy the network. Whenever I edit the version number there appears a red circle next to the version number and the Deploy changes button is disabled.

Comment: The version number you specify needs to be greater than the number already in use - perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: You are actually correct. But then I wonder if the instructions are out of date?